# How to create generic editing style for DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've created the following style for a DataGrid DataGridCheckBoxColumn:

```
<Style x:Key="TextColumnEditStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter...>
  <Setter...>
</Style>
```

Then on the DataGrid:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextColumnEditStyle}"...>
```

That works fine.

Is there a way to make the above a more generic style that targets DataGridCheckBoxColumn so I don't have to assign the style to each DataGridCheckBoxColumn?

I have tried the following but it had no effect:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCheckBoxColumn">
  <Setter...>
  <Setter...>
</Style>
```

...and then removed the style assignment:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn ...>
```

Comment: Based on your rep, I'm sure you know you can put it in a method and hit the method for every column rather than typing it individually. AFAIK, there is no way to set it by default. It's an interesting question, though. I'll keep my eyes peeled here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom column with this style set to it, and then instead of adding `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` you can add your own custom column and that will have your style applied

Create a new column say `MyColumn` so `MyColumn.xaml` looks like

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn  x:Class="TestApp.MyColumn"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
             EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextColumnEditStyle}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"/>
```

and `MyColumn.xaml.cs` looks like

```
public partial class MyColumn : DataGridCheckBoxColumn
{
    public MyColumn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and then your view that uses grid can use it like this

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <local:MyColumn Binding="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

you can create `TextColumnEditStyle` in a resource that will be used by new custom column.

Comment: Isn't that what I did? If not, can you show a code example?